# Getting 13 errors in my AndroidManifest.xml after migrating a Flutter project to AndroidX, Need Help Please

Tags: flutter, migration, android-manifest, androidx

[image]

I have a flutter project in which I added the dependency Multi_image_Picker and I when running the app, it stopped responding in

> resolving dependencies

. and the console showed errors asking me to migrate project to AndroidX.

I used instructions in this link to migrate to AndroidX. I used the selected answer. the first 3 steps didn't solved the issue so I went to 4 and all the way to the bottom.

I did that but although I still can run the app in both simulator and real device, i get 13 error about the AndroidManifest.xml when I try to commit the project and preview for errors and warnings.

I am afraid if commit the project with these errors later when compiling the app for Google Play upload I might get errors.

the AndroidMinifest shows several line of code in red and it shows these errors :

```
Error:(1, 2) Cannot find the declaration of element 'manifest'.
Error:(1, 26) URI is not registered (Settings | Languages & Frameworks | Schemas and DTDs).
Error:(13, 26) Unresolved package 'flutter'.
Error:(13, 34) Unresolved package 'app'
Error:(13, 38) Unresolved class 'FlutterApplication'.
Error:(15, 9) Attribute android:icon is not allowed here.
Error:(19, 28) Unresolved class 'MainActivity'.
Error:(20, 13) Attribute android:launchMode is not allowed here.
Error:(21, 13) Attribute android:theme is not allowed here.
Error:(22, 13) Attribute android:configChanges is not allowed here.
Error:(23, 13) Attribute android:hardwareAccelerated is not allowed here.
Error:(24, 13) Attribute android:windowSoftInputMode is not allowed here.
Error:(38, 3) Cannot find the declaration of element 'manifest'.
```

Comment: you found any solution for this?

Comment: Not really. No worries though, you don’t need one . I generated the app bundle and the apk and uploaded it to the google play store with no problems. Just commit it to version control with the errors and next time you wont see them unless you reopen the AndroidManifest.xml again and even then please go ahed and commit since these errors cause no problem

Comment: Just commit the with errors there won’t be a problem when submitting the app to google play store. These errors cause no problems.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just commit with the errors. These errors don’t cause problems in google play store when the app is submitted.